# Not able to import packages of Facebook Android SDK

Tags: android, facebook, import

When I tried to import the facebook SDK, I am not able to import the packages provided by facebook SDK.

I have tried following steps:

1. Cloned the sdk from git (path is -
   D:\gitrepository\facebook-android-sdk)
2. I had a project where i wanted to use facebook api.(path for my
   project is: D:\androidworkspace\ContactManager)
3. I imported the "facebook" folder from the "D:\git
   repository\facebook-android-sdk" in my eclipse.
4. Then i added internet permission to "ContactManager".
5. I used the command to get the hash key and registered it on fb.
6. Also in the ContactManager, right click -> properties -> Android
   ->Added library as "facebook".   Change the compiler version to 1.6

Now a red exclamation mark icon is visible on the *ContactManger*, FaceBook, and *FacebookTestActivity* as classes provided by Facebook project can not be resolved.

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

**facebook-android-sdk-3.0 library is used with minimum API:8. So Please try to lift up your project API to 8**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

`You can also check the API's Version at Run Time and modify your code basis on reflection or some another technique`

Comment: minSdkVersion is already 8, <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

Comment: @guptakvgaurav I'm sharing a link with you. Try to put these as a Facebook-library. I also faced some problems before. But these one is working way good for me. So give it a try :) https://www.dropbox.com/s/1scnypgoermluel/facebook.rar